# PHP, MySQL - grab files from server in an loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

sorry for the - maybe - wrong title, but I'm not an native english speaker and don't know who to explain my problem better.

I need to download images from an external server, one image for each dataset from the table.
I wrote already a code - based on ideas I found already.

This code is working when I test them with a small amount of datasets. But I want to run this script once a time and the table has up to 10.000 datasets.

I need an solution that the script will download the images (up to 5MB each) only in steps - maybe 100, then next 100, ...

or maybe there is an better solution with jQuery/Ajax? I have not much experience into jQuery and only basics with PHP.

This is my code:

```
foreach ($rs_post as $row) {

  $org_file    = 'http://domain.tld/' . $sub_dir . '/' . substr($row['sender_id'], 4) . '/' . $row['sender_id'] . '/pic_' . $row[$file_id] . $prefix . '.jpg';
  $target_file = '/path/' . $dir . '/pic_' . $row[$file_id] . $prefix . '.jpg';

  if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $ifmodhdr = 'If-Modified-Since: '.date( "r", filemtime($target_file))."\r\n";
  } else {
    $ifmodhdr = '';
  }
  $arrRequestHeaders = array( 'http'=>array( 'method' => 'GET', 'protocol_version' => 1.1, 'follow_location' => 1, 'header' => "User-Agent: Feed/1.0\r\n" . "Referer: $source\r\n" . $ifmodhdr ) );

  if (!file_exists($target_file)) {
    $success = copy( $org_file, $target_file, stream_context_create($arrRequestHeaders) );
    if($success) {
      echo '<li>'.$org_file.' : OK</li>';
    } else {
      echo '<li>'.$org_file.' : KO</li>';
    }
    ob_flush(); flush();
  }

}
```

When I run this script with all datasets I run into an timeout or memory problem. When I run this script just with a few datasets, it works.

Any tipps or tutorials for me?

Regards
Torsten

Comment: whats the source of the remote files?

Comment: Try setting the connection time out in your XAMPP Control Panel. Consider also the execution time of your code/query. Optimize it.

Comment: It's really not clear here what your objective is. jQuery and AJAX are for web client use only, so I'm not sure how that's relevant for batch downloading things. Is there anything here that's special or can you do this with a big list of URLs and a tool like [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)?

Comment: Yes @tadman I was thinking about wget also. Maybe I will write the output from the databse into an txt file and then start an shell script for download the images.

Comment: Sometimes the quick and dirty way is the best way to get started. You can always refine it from there.